# Install ODBC Driver for Mac pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, odbc

Working with my Mac trying to connect to SQL Server database.  Following [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  However, when I enter:

```
brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql@13.1.9.2 mssql-tools@14.0.6.0
```

I get the error:

```
odbcinst: SQLInstallDriverEx failed with Invalid install path.
```

If I install the ODBC driver (on top of Microsoft's instructions web page) and manually load into python script, is that possible?  Here is my python code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                       "Server=server_name;"
                       "Database=Sandbox;"
                       "uid=username;pwd=password")
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from table', cnxn)
```

In this code, how would I replace the zipped downloaded driver to the connect statement, thus bypassing brew?

Comment: I know nothing of macs but did you run `brew install...` and `brew update`? And no, drivers are softwares and need full installation to run inside code.

Answer (score 1):

> In this code, how would I replace the zipped downloaded driver to the connect statement, thus bypassing brew?

The answer to this is no, you cannot do what you're asking -- you're talking across purposes.  `brew` (Homebrew) is the package manager command that's required in this case to install the drivers on your Mac so your Python code can talk to the database.  Put simply, you can't run your Python code without the drivers installed so there isn't a way of bypassing it.

There have been more recent changes in the Homebrew tap (https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release) that you're using to install the drivers, including several [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+SQLInstallDriverEx+failed) that are akin to yours which are now closed/resolved.  So, try the following:

```
# This updates the tap and Homebrew to the latest versions
brew update

# Install the drivers; note options like `--no-sandbox` are no longer in Homebrew
brew install msodbcsql@13.1.9.2 mssql-tools@14.0.6.0
```

This works in my macOS 10.14 environment with Homebrew 2.0.1.  Check the file at `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` and you should see a reference to `[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]` defined.  You'll need to change your Python code to reflect the name of this new driver, like so:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
```